# Selenium IDE: Contains ID on two conditions

Tags: selenium-ide

I am a bit new to XPATHs. I am trying to find the password field on Quora website. This is how the HTML looks:

```
<input class="text header_login_text_box ignore_interaction" group="__w2_kIrXbkj_interaction" placeholder="Password" name="password" tabindex="2" w2cid="kIrXbkj" id="__w2_kIrXbkj_password" type="password">
```

I tried in the following ways but failed:

1. `//*[contains(@class, 'header_login_text_box')]` - then it finds the username field instead. Can I maybe specify that I want the 2nd result? I tried to add [2] in different places, but no luck.
2. `//id[contains(text(),'password')]`
3. I wanted to find it by ID that contains '_w2' and contains 'password', because if I just do contains 'password' it will find some other element instead. So I thought of something like _'w2*password', but that didn't work..

Probably I have some simple syntax problems..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. just now it struck me:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'header_login_text_box') and contains(@id,'password')]
```